# Weird and Irritating Problem With My 3rd Finger in Piano Performance

Tags: piano, practice, performance-practice

The story goes like this:

3-4 years ago I used to practice with [the Hanon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Virtuoso_Pianist_in_60_Exercises). I played the exercises with a fast tempo -- I didn't have good control of my left hand fingers, but I insisted on playing the exercise and continuing them with bad shape and ecole; and then gradually, this ended with my 3rd finger behaving weird:

I can't play with my left hand 3rd finger! I just can't! When I try hard to do it, my second finger first comes down (and so, unintentionally plays the key) *then*, probably with the help of this finger, my 3rd finger comes down.

Seems like it's paralysed. It's been years, and I don't know what to do; I have talked with several teachers but they also didn't have a clue.

Can you help me? Maybe you've heard something similar, or can suggest an exercise that might help?

Comment: Does the same thing outside playing piano? Or can you bend it without bending other fingers? Perhaps a bit more silly, can you put up your middle finger while having the other fingers bent? That might be an indication in how far it's wired into your brain, or how far it's (somehow) directly physical.

Comment: I cleaned this up a bit, but what's ecole?

Comment: First, do what joseem said.
Can you imitate your right hand with your left hand, so that you figure out what's different in your middle finger of your left hand?
Maybe you're too tense when playing.

Comment: Sounds like "yet another potential pianist physically injured by that nice Mr Hanon". All copies of those exercises should be burned, IMHO. People have been wrecking their hands by misguided practising like this for at least 150 years already. I don't know of any "cures" that really work.

Comment: @Evert in everyday life there isn't much delicate use of one's fingers. but also when typing sometimes i notice slight disablity.

Comment: @cfcief i've done so; i'm again going to go to a neurologist. i have examined well, the diffrence bethween right hand and left hand is that can play the key in right hand, and not in left hand.

Comment: @Alephzero and haven't you heard of someone who could get into a better situation also? by the way, isn't alephzero the cardinality of N?

Comment: @neilfein thanks pal. "ecole" is the physical aspects and form you play an instrument. The right way to play and use.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly recomend that you go to a specialist doctor. If there is a physical condition, anything you do may worse the situation and perhaps cause irreparable damage. If after doing a thorough examination there is no apparent physiological cause, then you may start to apply possible study and performance techniques to try to overcome your difficulty.

Comment: I went to a specialist once, and i'm to do that again. i will answer again when i got the results of the examinations from the next specialist...while i don't the sufficient hope....

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using metronome, if you are not, I recommend it and try very slow time (60bpm), sometimes less is more. Keep calm and no rush.

Comment: I even have tried by 40bpm. it's injured and is getting worse...